# How to remove GRUB and boot windows 10 directly from C drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, grub

I have 2 SSDs in my computer, lets call them disk A and disk B.

Windows 10 is installed in disk A, and some time ago I installed ubuntu on disk B, along with  grub to be able to dual boot.

Now I want to remove disk B to put it in some other computer (and leave this computer with windows 10 only), the problem is that windows won't boot without it because it boots through grub. How do I get windows to boot from disk A directly?

I tried booting from disk A in BIOS but it blue-screens saying that it can't load winload.exe

[image: partition scheme on disk A]

Comment: What is the partition scheme on disk A? I'm asking because if you installed Ubuntu on disk B than it shouldn't have overwritten the windows boot manager

Comment: added an image with the partitions in disk A

Comment: Download and boot from `AOMEI Partition Assistant` when you removed Ubuntu and follow menu to fix Windows boot

Answer (score 1):

From the photo you added you still have the partitions meaning you can safely restore windows boot loader from recovery mode via the installation media, I recommend searching in Google or YouTube for exact instructions on "how to restore windows boot manager with recovery".

Comment: will try this tomorrow with an installation media

Comment: so I tried to restore the windows boot manager and messed it up so the pc would no longer boot :) Anyways, I backed up all the data and reinstalled windows, it's awalys the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Leave disk B unconnected, boot Windows installation media and try out the repair installation feature.